# VBA Excel Paste Values Into New Cells Based On Found Value

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble pasting values into new cells, starting at "D5", until I run out of found values.  I can find the values and delete the cells for the row where the value is found, but I need to instead paste.  I want to be able to take column B and find all matches of $TC_TP2[2]="9070036" and only paste 9070036 in location "D5" and then find $TC_TP2[3]="9005270" and paste 9005270 in "D6" and so on finding every instance of $TC_TP2 and paste the value after the equal sign. I will paste the code I started below and it is a little long because I did not know how to do multiple searches in 1 loop so I did four loops.

```
Sub Find_Example()

    Dim calcmode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim TP2String As Variant
    Dim DP3String As Variant
    Dim MOP1String As Variant
    Dim MOP2String As Variant
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    With Application
        calcmode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'We use the ActiveSheet but you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    'We search in column B in this example
    Set myRng = sh.Range("B:B")

    'Add more search strings if you need
    TP2String = Array("*TC_TP2*")
    DP3String = Array("*TC_DP3*")
    MOP1String = Array("*TC_MOP1*")
    MOP2String = Array("*TC_MOP2*")


    With sh

        'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
        .Select

        'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
        'back to normal view, we do this for speed
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'We will search the values in MyRng in this example
        With myRng

            For I = LBound(TP2String) To UBound(TP2String)
                Do
                    Set FoundCell = myRng.Find(What:=TP2String(I), _
                                               After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                               MatchCase:=False)
                    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        **Range("D10").Select
                        FoundCell.Paste**        <---- Where I tried to paste
                    End If
                Loop
            Next I

        End With

    End With

    With sh
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'We will search the values in MyRng in this example


With myRng

            For I = LBound(DP3String) To UBound(DP3String)
                Do
                    Set FoundCell = myRng.Find(What:=DP3String(I), _
                                               After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                               MatchCase:=False)
                    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                Loop
            Next I

        End With

    End With

    With sh
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'We will search the values in MyRng in this example
        With myRng

            For I = LBound(MOP1String) To UBound(MOP1String)
                Do
                    Set FoundCell = myRng.Find(What:=MOP1String(I), _
                                               After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                               MatchCase:=False)
                    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                Loop
            Next I

        End With

    End With

    With sh
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'We will search the values in MyRng in this example
With myRng

            For I = LBound(MOP2String) To UBound(MOP2String)
                Do
                    Set FoundCell = myRng.Find(What:=MOP2String(I), _
                                               After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                               MatchCase:=False)
                    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                Loop
            Next I

        End With

    End With



    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = calcmode
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Snippet of the excel data:

Comment: $TC_TP1[2]=1
$TC_TP2[2]="9070036"
$TC_TP3[2]=1
$TC_TP4[2]=1
$TC_TP5[2]=1
$TC_TP6[2]=1
$TC_TP7[2]=1
$TC_TP8[2]=194
$TC_TP9[2]=1
$TC_TP10[2]=0
$TC_TP11[2]=0
$TC_TPC1[2]=9
$TC_TPC2[2]=0
$TC_DP1[2,1]=120
$TC_DP2[2,1]=0
$TC_DP3[2,1]=179.85
$TC_DP4[2,1]=0
$TC_TP2[3]="9005270"
$TC_TP3[3]=1
$TC_TP4[3]=1
$TC_TP5[3]=1
$TC_TP6[3]=1
$TC_TP7[3]=1
$TC_TP8[3]=194
$TC_TP9[3]=1
$TC_TP10[3]=0
$TC_TP11[3]=0
$TC_TPC1[3]=0
$TC_TPC2[3]=0
$TC_DP1[3,1]=120
$TC_DP2[3,1]=0
$TC_DP3[3,1]=173.479
$TC_DP4[3,1]=0

Comment: Where you marked `Where I tried to paste` - write this one line: `Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).Offset(1).Value = FoundCell.Value`

Comment: I tried the code addition without Range("D10").Select because it kept throwing and error about Range, so I removed it, but now it runs until I have to close it because it does not work.  Is it going out of bounds? I am new to vba and not 100% on the coding.